# How to pass a boolean value from one class to another and back?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to use the `Visibility` widget to show and hide my page. Here is my logic when at the first page the booean `isVisible` is true showing the `Container` widget but as I go to another screen I set the boolean `isVisiblevis` to false such that my container hides and maintains it state. When I come back from the second screen I want to set the boolean back to true hence showing my container.

First page

```
class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
 bool isVisible = true;

  MainScreen({this.isVisible});

 ...
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  body: Container(
            //change the margin
            margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 300),
            child: isVisible ?
            Visibility(
                maintainAnimation: true,
                maintainState: true,
                child: (Container(
                        Text ('first page')
                 ): Container ()

                 .....
                 GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        isVisible= false; //set the visibility false
                        Navigator.push(
                            //send to search screen
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => (SecondScreen())));
                       
                      },
```

Now on the second page when I pop how do I set the boolean `isVisible` back to true on first page ?

```
  GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
            Navigator.pop(
                //send back data
                context,
                dropOffTextEditingController.text,
            );
            MainScreen(mapVisible: true,); //doesn't work
        },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer title and function parameters.

`screenone.dart`

```
class ScreenOne extends StatefulWidget {
  ScreenOne({Key key = const Key("ScreenOne")}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ScreenOneState createState() => _ScreenOneState();
}

class _ScreenOneState extends State<ScreenOne> {
  bool checkScreenOneValue = true;
  
 @override
  void initState() {
    checkScreenOneValue = true;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          'Screen One',
        ),
      ),
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => ScreenTwo(
                        testFunction: testFunction, title: "Screen two")));
          },
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
              "Screen Two",
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  testFunction(bool checkValue) {
    checkScreenOneValue = checkValue;
    print("****TestFunction $checkScreenOneValue");
  }
}
```

`screentwo.dart`

```
class ScreenTwo extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function testFunction;
  final String title;

  const ScreenTwo({required this.testFunction, required this.title});
  @override
  _ScreenTwoState createState() => _ScreenTwoState();
}

class _ScreenTwoState extends State<ScreenTwo> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          widget.title,
        ),
      ),
      body: InkWell(
        child: Center(child: Text("Back")),
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.pop(context);
          widget.testFunction(false);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey Thankyou! I understand now how to send the boolean value back, but how do I initialize testFunction as true on the first page?

Comment: @pannam updated answer you can have a local variable and set the value in `initState`

Answer (score 1):

See what is happening here, when you are setting the `isVisible` to false you have to use it on the second page means that you have to pass the `isVisible` data from one page to another. You can refer [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/passing-data):

`first.dart`

```
class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  bool isVisible = true;

  MainScreen({this.isVisible});

}

Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Second(data: isVisible)));
```

`second.dart`

```
class Second extends StatefulWidget {
  final String data;

  MyPosts({this.data});
}
```

you can use as `widget.data`

Comment: How do I use `widget.isVisible` on the second screen tho ? Thats where I am stuck, I updated my constructer as per your say in the first screen.