# How to manage a widget state in another widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web, flutter-widget

I have recently started working with flutter and flutter web. What is best practice to change state of a widget which is in one file (content_table.dart) from another file (tables_display.dart)

**tables_display.dart**:

```
import 'package:portal/components/content_table.dart';

class TableDisplay extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TableDisplayState createState() => _TableDisplayState();
}

class _TableDisplayState extends State<TableDisplay> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: 700,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(),
        child: DefaultTabController(
          length: 3,
          initialIndex: 0,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                child: TabBar(
                  labelStyle:
                      TextStyle(fontSize: 12, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                  isScrollable: true,
                  indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize
                      .label, //make the indicator the same size as the label
                  labelPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 0, 5, 0),
                  labelColor: FlutterFlowTheme.primaryColor,
                  unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black54,
                  indicatorColor: FlutterFlowTheme
                      .primaryColor, //adds color to the indicator
                  tabs: [
                    Container(
                      // decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      //   borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0),
                      //   border: Border(
                      //       top: BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.red),
                      //       left: BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.red),
                      //       right: BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.red)),
                      //   //border: Border.all(color: Colors.redAccent, width: 1)
                      // ),
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(25, 5, 25, 0),
                        child: Tab(
                          text: 'Easy',
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(25, 5, 25, 0),
                      child: Tab(
                        text: 'Medium',
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(25, 5, 25, 0),
                      child: Tab(
                        text: 'Hard',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                // decoration: BoxDecoration(
                //     border: Border(
                //   top: BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.red),
                // )),

                color: Colors.white,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0, bottom: 20),
                  child: TabBarView(
                    children: [
                      ContentTable(),
                      ContentTable(),
                      ContentTable(),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              )),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In above code, I have created a DefaultTabController which is made up of 3 tabs; Easy, Medium and Hard, each of the tabs have access to ContentTable() widget that's in the content_table.dart file
I want that when a **SPECIFIC** tab is clicked it rebuilds the ContentTable() widget in the widget tree with data specified. How would you go about that?

**content_table.dart:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ContentTable extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ContentState createState() => _ContentState();
}

class _ContentState extends State<ContentTable> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      //decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey[100])),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            DataTable(
                showCheckboxColumn: true,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border(
                    top: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey[100], width: 1),
                    bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey[100], width: 1),
                  ),
                ),
                headingRowColor: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith(
                    (states) => Colors.grey.shade50),
                columns: [
                  DataColumn(
                    label: Text("ID", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 11)),
                  ),
                  DataColumn(
                    label: Text("Question", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 11)),
                  ),
                  DataColumn(
                    label: Text("Opt. 1", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 11)),
                  ),
                  DataColumn(
                    label: Text("Opt. 2", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 11)),
                  ),
                  DataColumn(
                    label: Text("Opt. 3", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 11)),
                  ),
                  DataColumn(
                    label: Text("Opt. 4", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 11)),
                  ),
                  DataColumn(
                    label: Text("Explanation", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 11)),
                  ),
                  DataColumn(
                    label: Text("Image", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 11)),
                  ),
                ],
                rows: [])
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: try this to pass value and get call back from other widget https://stackoverflow.com/a/68259836/2804581

Comment: thats' call `stateManagement` try using `provider` / `riverpod` or anyOther package, also as @DineshNagarajan said, you can use callBack for small task.

Comment: Im new to flutter so i dont really understand the passing of data or information between widgets

Comment: As mentioned, provider or riverpod are the generally accepted ways to do this. These libraries help you to "lift state", which refers to storing the relevant state in a widget "higher" in the widget tree, which is a common ancestor of the two widgets you want to be able to connect. To read more: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple

Comment: just use GetX, there is exactly one tutorial for your problem. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RaqPIoJSTtI

Answer (score 0):

For this particular issue, the solution is very simple. Passing data between widgets has nothing to do with which files they are defined in, only where in your app they are actually used. It looks like you are using `ContentTable` as a child widget of `TableDisplay` so you can pass information to it without problem. Just define a parameter in content_table.dart and supply a value for that parameter when you call `ContentTable` in your tables_display.dart, for instance:

**content_table.dart**

```
class ContentTable extends StatefulWidget {
  final bool hard;

  ContentTable(
    {this.hard = false}
  );

  @override
  _ContentState createState() => _ContentState();
}

class _ContentState extends State<ContentTable> {
  //...if(widget.hard) {...
```

**tables_display.dart**

```
//...
TabBarView(
  children: [
    ContentTable(hard: true), //hard will be true
    ContentTable(), //hard will remain false
    ContentTable(hard: true), //hard will be true
  ],
),
//...
```

If you want to pass data between widgets used in totally different parts of your app then use [Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider)

Comment: Thanks and i kinda understand a little more how provider works with some reading and experimentation but this worked perfectly