# best way to share data between pages in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have many pages and I want to share file content between some pages, also giving this pages ability to modify content, the file contains `(obj, data (int, bool, ...)).`

[image]

Comment: this can give you an idea https://stackoverflow.com/a/68259836/2804581

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1st: `share file content between some pages` can be done by using `Constructor`.

2nd: `ability to modify conten` can only be done by `global variable+ key`, but go for `stateManagement`.

I suggest, you should go for [StateManagement](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options). It can handle that.
I perefer using [riverpod](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options), also people suggest using `getx` being easy to use.

for more read [this.](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the provider package as it's an effective tool for sharing data a cross your flutter app: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple

Answer (score 0):

Either use **constructors** to dig through the widgets or simply use one of the packages for state management like **provider, getx, bloc** and many others.

But if you are a beginner then go with **provider package** as it is recommended by **flutter team**