# How can i pass data to the pervious page using WillPopScope

Tags: dataframe, flutter, dart, scope, zip

**Flutter Dart**

i need to pass data to previous page , i have no idea how can i handle with this , any help will be thankful , thanks

```
 WillPopScope(
            onWillPop: () async{


             
              Navigator.pop(context, false );
              
              return Future.value(false);
            },
```

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/68259836/2804581

Comment: thanks but didnt help

Answer (score 0):

try this code in first screen to `push`:

```
   var res = await Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute<bool>(
        builder: (BuildContext context) => const SecondScreen(),
      ),
    );
    
    print(res.toString());
```