# How to pass values to the another screen by the onTap function in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have two pages. one is Route, the second is Stops. Also, my code contains an algorithm that is sorted stops by the routes. When I did the test example and pass the stops on the same page as routes, so everything works fine, but for better UI I want to put arguments in the constructor and in onTap method. How can I pass arguments from this algorithm and terms from another screen into another screen?

the first screen:

```
     body: FutureBuilder(
            future: getMarshrutWithStops(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
              List<RouteWithStops> routes = snapshot.data;
              print(routes?.toString());
              return (routes == null)
     onTap: () {
                                Navigator.push(
                                    context,
                                    MaterialPageRoute(
                                        builder: (context) => StopsPage(
                                         stId: routes[index].stop[index].stId
                                        )));
                              },


    //the algorithm which is sorted everything by id's

    Future<List<RouteWithStops>> getMarshrutWithStops() async {
        List<Routes> routes = [];
        List<ScheduleVariants> variants = [];
        List<StopList> stops = [];
        final TransportService transService = TransportService();
    
        routes.addAll((await transService.fetchroutes()).toList());
    
        stops.addAll(await transService.fetchStops());
        variants.addAll(await transService.fetchSchedule());
    
        List<RouteWithStops> routesWithStops = [];
    
        for (Routes route in routes) {
          final routeWithStops = RouteWithStops();
    
          routesWithStops.add(routeWithStops);
          routeWithStops.route = route;
    
          routeWithStops.variant =
              variants.where((variant) => variant.mrId == route.mrId).first;
    
          List<RaceCard> cards = [];
    
          cards.addAll(
              await transService.fetchRaceCard(routeWithStops.variant.mvId));
          print(cards);
          List<StopList> currentRouteStops = [];
    
          cards.forEach((card) {
            stops.forEach((stop) {
              if (card.stId == stop.stId) {
                currentRouteStops.add(stop);
              }
            });
          });
          routeWithStops.stop = currentRouteStops;
        }
        return routesWithStops;
      }
```

The second page where I want all sorted stops be stored:

```
    class StopsPage extends StatelessWidget {
    
     final int stId;
      const StopsPage({Key key, this.stId}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(),
          body: FutureBuilder(
            future: getMarshrutWithStops(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
              List<RouteWithStops> routes = snapshot.data;
              print(routes?.toString());
              return (routes == null)
                  ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
                  : ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: routes.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return ListTile(
                          title: Text(routes[index].stop.toString()),
                        );
                      });
            },
          ),
        );
      }
    
      Future<List<RouteWithStops>> getMarshrutWithStops() async {
        List<Routes> routes = [];
        List<ScheduleVariants> variants = [];
        List<StopList> stops = [];
        final TransportService transService = TransportService();
    
        routes.addAll((await transService.fetchroutes()).take(10).toList());
    
        stops.addAll(await transService.fetchStops());
        variants.addAll(await transService.fetchSchedule());
    
        List<RouteWithStops> routesWithStops = [];
    
        for (Routes route in routes) {
          final routeWithStops = RouteWithStops();
    
          routesWithStops.add(routeWithStops);
          routeWithStops.route = route;
    
          routeWithStops.variant =
              variants.where((variant) => variant.mrId == route.mrId).first;
    
          List<RaceCard> cards = [];
    
          cards.addAll(
              await transService.fetchRaceCard(routeWithStops.variant.mvId));
          print(cards);
          List<StopList> currentRouteStops = [];
    
          cards.forEach((card) {
            stops.forEach((stop) {
              if (card.stId == stop.stId) {
                currentRouteStops.add(stop);
              }
            });
          });
          routeWithStops.stop = currentRouteStops;
        }
        return routesWithStops;
      }
    }
```

I just thought that I didn’t need to copy and paste the entire algorithm on all pages, maybe I only need a part of the algorithm that starts with a for-loop and transfer it to the second page, where all the filtered stops should be. I can't figure out what to put in the onTap function and what to pass to the constructor on the Stops page.

Comment: refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/68259836/2804581

Comment: try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68494291/13997210) answer

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this

In *`onTap`* of **`First Page`** pass the value as **`name parameter`**

```
onTap: () {
  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
   builder: (context) => StopPage(stId: routes[index].stop[index].stId))
  );
}
```

Excess the same on **`StopPage`**, by using the constructor

```
class StopPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final dynamic stId;

  StopPage({this.stId});
}
```